# Trying to load two vertically image in a Screen

Tags: android, list, view

Need some help!!..
I'm try to implement a list view with two images in the initial screen, after scrolling other images can be seen.
Can you suggest anyway to implement it!

Answer (score 0):

Use can achieve it by creating custom adapter for list view. Have a look :-
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

You need to do some updation like removing text view from custom list layout.

Comment: Yep!!.  I have implemented custom list view, in the custom row layout i want an image to fill the half of the screen. So while running the code. It has to show two images in the screen. but its not working properly.

Comment: For this you have to calculate current device height and set height/2 to your image view height.
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight(); 

Set height/2 to your image view height dynamically.